# How to store a TRttiMethod reference to a variable?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I want to store the constructor method of a class I do not know at compile time, so I can call it later to create an object of the specified class. If possible, I don't want to use `TClass.Create` since it does not call the default constructor for the object.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Rtti;

type
  TClass1 = class
    constructor Create(pInt: Integer);
  end;

constructor TClass1.Create(pInt: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure PrintMethod(FMethod: TRttiMethod);
begin
  writeln(Format('Address: %d, Value Adress: %d, Method: %s,  Handle: %d, Params: %d, ClassName: %s',
      [Integer(FMethod), Integer(Addr(FMethod)), FMethod.Name, Integer(FMethod.Handle), Length(FMethod.GetParameters), FMethod.Parent.AsInstance.MetaclassType.ClassName]));
end;

function FindCreateMethod(pClass: TClass): TRttiMethod;
var
  rContext: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  FMethods: TArray<TRttiMethod>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  rContext:= TRttiContext.Create;
  rType:= rContext.GetType(pClass);
  FMethods:= rType.GetMethods;
  for I:= Low(FMethods) to High(FMethods) do
    if SameText('Create', FMethods[I].Name) then
    begin
      Result:= FMethods[I];
      Break;
    end;
  PrintMethod(Result);
end;

var
  FMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  FMethod:= FindCreateMethod(TClass1);//Prints: Address: 39354896, Value Adress: 1703672, Method: Create,  Handle: 4654648, Params: 1, ClassName: TClass1
  // Outside the scope of the function FindCreateMethod GetParameters does not work for FMethod
  PrintMethod(FMethod); //Prints: Address: 39354896, Value Adress: 1703740, Method: Create,  Handle: 4654648, Params: 0, ClassName: TClass1

  with TRttiContext.Create do
    GetType(TClass1).GetMethods; // After GetMethods call the value of FMethod changes

  PrintMethod(FMethod); //Prints: Address: 39354896, Value Adress: 1703740, Method: Destroy,  Handle: 4200544, Params: 0, ClassName: TObject
  readln;
end.
```

What is going on here? Apparently every time `GetMethods()` gets called, it  recreates the `TRTTIMethod` instances for the type. Is there a reliable way to store the `TRttiMethod` instance without having to loop through all the methods every single time?

I am using Delphi Berlin 10.1 update 2.

**Solved**: Thanks to @RemyLebeau comment the problem was solved by having a global TRTTiContext instance. Apparently there is information in TRTTIContext that is reference-counted, and, since the only instance of TRTTIcontext was the one I was creating inside the `FindCreateMethod` function, when it went out of scope the reference count goes to 0 and the TRTTIMethods instance was lost.

Comment: FYI, not all class constructors are named `'Create'`. You should be checking the `TRTTIMethod.MethodKind` property for `mkConstructor` (or calling the `TRttiMethod.IsConstructor()` method), not checking the `TRTTIMethod.Name` property for `'Create'` specifically.

Comment: Also, internally, the `TRTTIMethod` objects (and other RTTI objects) are maintained by a reference-counted singleton object that is referenced inside the `TRTTIContext`, and thus are only valid for use while that object remains alive. For what you are attempting, you should create a global `TRTTIContext` to keep the RTTI singleton alive for the lifetime of your program.  Even if you create a new `TRTTIContext` on each search, you don't want to have to recreate the singleton over and over.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for the tip on checking the method type, I will definetely use that. Will change the test app to use a global TRTTIContext and come back with the results. In any case, I don't think I Will be able to store the trttimethod instance If I have to rely on TRttiContext.Create be called only once.

Comment: you can call `TRTTIContext.Create` multiple times. But you should keep a global `TRTTIContext` so access to RTTI is more efficient when you do have multiple calls.

Comment: `internally, the TRTTIMethod objects (and other RTTI objects) are maintained by a reference-counted singleton object that is referenced inside the TRTTIContext`. That was it. With a global TRTTIContext it works as expected. That should be the anwer.

Comment: @MarceloRauter, please add your last edit as an answer, instead of embedding it into the question. And yes, using TRTTIContext as a global avoids some hard to find errors when using RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RemyLebeau 's comment the problem was solved by having a global TRTTiContext instance. Apparently there is information in TRTTIContext that is reference-counted, and, since the only instance of TRTTIcontext was the one I was creating inside the FindCreateMethod function, when it went out of scope the reference count goes to 0 and the TRTTIMethods instance was lost.